# Combining multiple ng-apps into a single app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**The Problem:** We have multiple angular apps running on the same page. One for the footer. One for the header and one for a login modal. Each with it's own state and each user ui.router.

**The challange:** We would like to combine them into a single ng-app in the least invasive manner. The main issue here is that when we try to combine them, switching states causes some areas to disappear,

Our first "naive" approach is to do something like:

```
angular
  .module('bigApp', ['smallApp1', 'smallApp2'])
  .run(['$state', function($state) {
    console.log("Big app running!");
  }]);
```

This seems to result in selective rendering. For example. When I click a link to go to a state defined in `smallApp1` the view for `smallApp2` disappears.

Am I correct in my assumption that a new common parent state will have to be created? The parent state will need to have subviews to render the small apps that need to stay in place? and not disappear when state changes?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are asking for suggestions, that's not a good fit for Stack Overflow because there is no single correct answer. You should look at your options and ask a more focused question.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't make a single, larger ng-controller for all three?

Comment: I just updated my question with more specifics. Hopefully it's less general.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to map out your new states and components. You can use hierarchical states, so for example the

```
"menu" state - contains navigation, status  bar (always present)
"menu.home" - contains the central home page
"menu.people" - contains your list of people
"menu.people.individual" - contains details of an individual (a sub view of "menu.people")
```

Once you have mapped out your structure, you can work out which parts will use ui-view, and which will use components. Each component can have its own controller under one app.